# How to call js function from a typescript-file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript-file with a function that contains an ajaxcall. Im trying to call that function from my typescript-file. Im guessing its because I did not declare the types but Im not sure how to write this?

I tried to add some type declarations but Visual Studio still complains about `getJsonNoCache`. I get the error

> "Error    TS2339  (TS) Property 'getJsonNoCache' does not exist on type '{
>   postJson(url: string, command: any, onSuccess?: any, onError?: any):
>   void; getJson(url: string, query: any, onSuccess?: any, onError?:
>   any): void; }'."

Here is my javascriptfile that is included as a bundle to my website.

```js
scp.network.getJsonNoCache = function(url, query, onSuccess, onError, statusCodeEvents) {
  $.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: query,
    cache: false,
    statusCode: {
      401: function() {
        window.location = '/';
      },
      405: function() {
        rfq.mainModel.errorHeader('Information');
      }
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (onSuccess !== undefined)
        onSuccess(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      if (onError !== undefined) {
        onError(data);
      }
    },
    dataType: "json",
  });
};
```

Here is the function in my ts-file where im trying to call the function.

```js
this.getUsers = (callback: any, text: string) => {
  if (text.length < 2) {
    callback([]);
    return;
  }

  scp.network.getJsonNoCache(audit.queries.GET_INTERNAL_USERS, {
    searchText: text,
    maxCount: 10,
    roleId: 5
  }, function(data: any) {
    this.queriedUsers = data.users;
    console.log(data.users);

    callback(_.map(this.queriedUsers, function(user: any) {
      return user.name;
    }));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is assert `scp.network` as type `any` to make transpiler skip checking for the properties of `scp.network`:

```
(scp.network as any).getJsonNoCache(...)
```

If you want to make it more type correctness, you can `declare` type for scp:

```
declare var scp: {
  network: {
    getJsonNoCache: (
      url: string,
      query: Record<string, string | number>,
      onSuccess?: (data: any) => void,
      onError?: (error: any) => void,
    ) => void;
  };
};
```

The above code tell TypeScript transpiler that your runtime has a global variable `scp` which type like this, then transpiler can tell from the declaration and check the type correctness for you.